# Run a shell script before a gradle build in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

Is it possible to run a unix shell script in Android Studio before every (gradle) build?

I'm having some trouble with gradle builds taking forever and one (admittedly bad) solution that works is to kill all java processes if they hold more than say 6Mb memory.

What I would like to do is run a shell script that does that before every build in Android Studio.

I'm not looking to add a gradle task to run before my build. That won't work because if I kill all java processes, gradle will also be killed.

So again:
Can I set up Android Studio (or gradlew) to run a script before building?

Comment: Follow up question: I'm wondering if it's possible to set something like this up to run before the "GRADLE SYNC" step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instruction for Intellij Idea, but I hope it works for Android Studio

1. Edit configirations...

[image]

2. Select\create run configuration for gradle build. Add "before launch" option

[image]

3. Select ptoper option. For example - "Run external tool"

[image]

Comment: This works exactly the same way in Android Studio. Thank you! It's very hidden though, you have to scroll down on that page. If you don't know that there's something there (the 'Before launch' section), you'd have no idea.

Comment: Follow up question: I'm wondering if it's possible to set something like this up to run before the "GRADLE SYNC" step.

Comment: Does this work for any command? For the `export` command it says `Target file "export" not found`.

Comment: I used this and pointed it to a `.command` file (on Mac)

Comment: Seems to be for running something before _launch_; not before build as I need and OP asks.